# Git: Apply old version of a file to a branch

Tags: git, version-control

Say file xyz.ext in the head/master is v1.25, but I want to commit v1.23 to the branch called QA...  How do I do it?

Based on my previous question, it's unlikely I can use `git merge` because I don't see anything about versions in the documentation I'm finding through google.  Is that correct?

Comment: This is appropriate for stackoverflow.com and doesn't really belong on programmers.

Comment: @Ken, @Renesis: I've msg'd the moderators to move to SO.  Wasn't sure which was best.

Comment: It's a cold day in hell when a Programmers question is moved to SO. It's always been the other way around.

Comment: @chrisaycock - I've moved several questions to SO - including this one ;)

Comment: @chrisaycock: Is there a badge for that? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout QA
git checkout <hash_or_tag_of_old_commit> -- xyz.ext
git add xyz.ext
git commit
```

Note that you can't follow the history of the file in the QA branch to see the history in the master branch.

Comment: Hash -- You mean SHA1?  If so, assume there is no such in master.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Hash, as in the commit id of the commit you want to take xyz.ext from. You can get this by looking at `git log master`.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your reference to a version number. Are you saying that you want to roll back a specific file to an earlier version?

If so, first identify identify the commit hash of when you want to move back to and verify using the following:

```
git diff commit xyz.ext
```

Then use the reset command to revert that file:

```
git reset commit xyz.ext
```